# Material-UI AppBar Buttons jump to center of screen when page is refreshed

Tags: javascript, user-interface, material-ui, appbar

I have this Material-UI AppBar:

```
import React from 'react'
import AppBar from 'material-ui/AppBar'
import AccountCircle from 'material-ui-icons/AccountCircle'
import Toolbar from 'material-ui/Toolbar'
import IconButton from 'material-ui/IconButton'
import HomeIcon from 'material-ui-icons/Home'
import Button from 'material-ui/Button'
import auth from './../auth/auth-helper'
import {Link, withRouter} from 'react-router-dom'

const isActive = (history, path) => {
  if (history.location.pathname == path)
    return {color: '#c61054'}
  else
    return {color: '#ffffff'}

}
const Menu = withRouter(({history}) => (
  <AppBar position="static">
    <Toolbar>
      <Link to="/">
        <IconButton aria-label="Home" style={isActive(history, "/")}>
          <HomeIcon/>
        </IconButton>
      </Link>
      {
        auth.isAuthenticated() && (<span style={{ marginLeft: "auto" }}>
          <Link to="/issues">
            <Button style={isActive(history, "/issues")}>Issues
            </Button>
          </Link>
          <Link to="/users">
            <Button style={isActive(history, "/users")}>Users
            </Button>
          </Link>
          <Link to="/signup">
            <Button style={isActive(history, "/signup")}>Create User
            </Button>
          </Link>
        </span>)
      } 
      {
        !auth.isAuthenticated() && (<span style={{ marginLeft: "auto", marginRight: -12 }}>
          <Link to="/signin">
            <Button style={isActive(history, "/signin")}>Sign In
            </Button>
          </Link>
        </span>)
      }
      {
        auth.isAuthenticated() && (<span  style={{ marginLeft: "auto", marginRight: -12 }}>
          <Link to={"/user/" + auth.isAuthenticated().user._id}>
            <IconButton aria-label="MyProfile" style={isActive(history, "/user/" + auth.isAuthenticated().user._id)}>
              <AccountCircle/>
            </IconButton>
          </Link>
          <Button color="inherit" onClick={() => {
              auth.signout(() => history.push('/'))
            }}>Sign Out</Button>
        </span>)
      }
    </Toolbar>
  </AppBar>
))

export default Menu
```

When logged out everything appears as expected. The `Home` icon is to the left and `SIGNIN` is to the right:

[image]

I then sign in and again, everything is as I would like. The `Home` icon, `ISSUES`, `USERS` and `CREATE USER` are to the left and the `Profile` icon and `SIGNOUT` are to the right:

[image]

If I then refresh the page, `ISSUES`, `USERS` and `CREATE USER` jump to the center of the page:

[image]

How do I stop this from happening? Should I try adding some condition to isActive to set this? Perhaps I could pass `left` or `right` in the function call and depending on which it is the style could be set on the button. Any thoughts on that?

Answer (score 0):

To avoid this kind of positioning issues maybe you could create 2 `span`containers, one with the options on the left and another one with the options on the right. Then you can set `display: flex;` and `justify-content:space-between;` to their parent container (in this case, `<Toolbar>`), so both of the `span` will be on opposite sides. What do you think about it?

Comment: Thanks, I tried that but havind 2 `span` containers seemed to be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is due to using the margin-left of "auto". You shouldn't need any margin on the authenticated span:

```
{
  auth.isAuthenticated() && (<span>
    <Link to="/issues">
      // ...existing code
    </Link>
  </span>)
}
```

If you want to use margin to push the element to the left, I think it should be:

```
margin-right: "auto";
```